# A* 8-puzzle problem worst case memory usage

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis, searching, space-analysis

We are testing the A* algorithm with Hamming and Manhattan on the 8-puzzle (and its natural generalization n-puzzle) problem.
We have to answer the following question but I can't figure out what it should be.

Our assignment is derived from [this](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spr10/cos226/assignments/8puzzle.html).

> How many board positions are in worst case in memory in function of board size N (where N is the side of a board of size NxN). Give a as low as possible upper bound. You can assume that a board configuration is never in the priority queue several times.

I was thinking about N^2! but that is impossible because not every board position can be reached.

Comment: @Principis: Websites disappears. When the linked site disappears, your question makes no sense whatsoever anymore. PS. Sam Loyd claimed to have invented it, but he didn't.

Comment: @gnasher729 what do you suggest to change it to? The 8-puzzle problem is pretty standard as far as I know. I mean I can't copy the whole assignment here because it's not in English and itś very long.

Comment: I've never, ever heard of it under the name. Actually, you could buy cheap plastic toys for what you would call the "15-puzzle" (haven't seen them in years), but I've never heard of either "15-puzzle" nor "8-puzzle".

Answer (score 0):

Since the number of possible positions is quite low when N = 3 (9! / 2 = 181,400), you can do an exhaustive search to find the worst case. Check the result, and maybe it leads to some insight.